# Windows 8.1 Settings - Confirmation Message

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

Can the system **prompt a message** for me to confirm `(yes or no)` my action when I was attempted to move a file to recycle bin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Right-click on **Recycle Bin** icon on Desktop and select **Properties**.
2. Now enable "**Display delete confirmation dialog**" option and apply the changes.